# White space below content - Fixes itself if window is resized (AdminLTE + angular.js)

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

Basically there is a white blank space below my content and it appears when I refresh the page and it "fixes" itself when I manually resize the page.

I'm using Angular with ui router, and Admin LTE 2 free bootstrap template. Everything loads fine, I'm not getting any errors what so ever, and I've included all neccessary files.

I'v tried to debug this with chrome tools, but it feels like it's not a css problem.

index.html inside body i've this ui-view

```
    <div ui-view="index-view"></div>
```

And inside main.html

```
<div class="wrapper">

<!-- HEADER -->
<div ng-include="'views/app/includes/header.html'"></div>

<!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div ng-include="'views/app/includes/sidebar.html'"></div>



<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div ui-view="content-view"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div ng-include="'views/app/includes/footer.html'"></div>
```

And here are my routes

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/landing");

$stateProvider
.state('landing_login_state', {
    url: "/landing",

    views: {
        'index-view@': {
            templateUrl: "views/landing/login.html",
            controller: "LoginCtrl as login",
        }
    }
})
.state('app', {
    url: "/main",

    views: {
        'index-view': {
            templateUrl: 'views/app/main.html'
        },
        'content-view@app': {
            templateUrl: "views/app/main_content.html"
        },

    }
})
.state('app.newbook', {
    url: "/new_newbook",

    views: {
        'index-view': {
            templateUrl: 'views/app/main.html'
        },
        'content-view@app': {
            templateUrl: "views/app/new_book.html"
        }
    }
});
```

I'm suspecting I've done something horribly wrong with ui router, but I'm not sure. I can run the starter page of Admin LTE 2 just fine without ui-router, so this my strongest bet.